# fasterxml JsonInclude for optional

Tags: java, option-type, fasterxml

I have a dto as the following

```
public class MyClass {
    @JsonProperty("value")
    @JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_EMPTY)
    public Optional<String> myValue = Optional.empty();
}
```

When I test serialization

```
 @Test
    public void should() throws JsonProcessingException {
        //GIVEN
        val myClass = new MyClass();
        myClass.myValue =(Optional.empty());

        //WHEN
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        String valueAsString = mapper.writeValueAsString(myClass);
        System.out.println(valueAsString);
        //THEN

    }
```

empty optional  filed is still serialized

```
{"value":{"present":false}}
```

I've tried using Include.NON_ABSENT and user annotation on the whole class - still the filed is serialized.

Comment: The optional is serialized because it is not null. You have to differentiate between if myValue == null and myValue is an optional which is empty.

Comment: NON_ABSENT should work with optional 

        /**
         * Value that indicates that properties are included unless their value
         * is:
         *<ul>
         *  <li>null</li>
         *  <li>"absent" value of a referential type (like Java 8 `Optional`, or
         *     {link java.utl.concurrent.atomic.AtomicReference}); that is, something
         *     that would not deference to a non-null value.
         * </ul>
         * This option is mostly used to work with "Optional"s (Java 8, Guava).
         *
         * @since 2.6
         */

Comment: Oh ok. I didn't know that before. So do you use jackson in version 2.6 or higher?

Comment: Yes    'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.9.1'. And I've tried other versions just in case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In some examples I saw that the objectMapper register a jdk8Module. Did you try this? Maybe it only handles the Optional-Instances correct with this module registered.

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
mapper.registerModule(new Jdk8Module());
```